# some errors about rabbitmq-erlang-client

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to use rabbitmq-erlang-client, and confused about errors throwed by program.
I fllowed `system_SUITE:queue_unbind/1` But errors are throwed when  setting Exchange and Queue :

```
%% code
amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'exchange.declare'{exchange = X}),
amqp_channel:call(Channel, #'queue.declare'{queue = Q}),



%%  it throw me same errors again and again:
** Last message in was setup_exchange_queue
** When Server state == {state,
                            {amqp_params_network,<<"username">>,<<"password">>,
                                <<"/">>,"192.168.1.173",5672,0,0,10,infinity, 
                                none,
                                [#Fun<amqp_auth_mechanisms.plain.3>,
                                 #Fun<amqp_auth_mechanisms.amqplain.3>],
                                [],[]},
                            <0.74.0>,<0.83.0>,<<"amq.direct">>,<<"queue">>,
                            <<"my_queue">>,undefined,undefined}
** Reason for termination == 
** {{noproc,{gen_server,call,[<0.83.0>,{close,200,<<"Goodbye">>},infinity]}}, 
    [{gen_server,call,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,212}]},
     {mrbq,terminate,2,[{file,"src/mrbq.erl"},{line,244}]},
     {gen_server,try_terminate,3,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,643}]},
     {gen_server,terminate,7,[{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,809}]},
     {proc_lib,init_p_do_apply,3,[{file,"proc_lib.erl"},{line,240}]}]}
** exception exit: {noproc,
                       {gen_server,call,
                           [<0.83.0>,{close,200,<<"Goodbye">>},infinity]}}
```

code review `amqp_channel.erl`

```
%% call
call/2 -> gen_server:call/2  
handle_call/3 -> handle_method_to_server/6
```

goto **line 573**, then **line 888** ,and `{noreply, State}` returned for **`call`** as a result!!

What's wrong  with above steps?
What should do to make it OK?

I have had tried `cast/2`,and no errors occur. But this is not what I need.